# Loading an NSString to NSInputStream

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsinputstream

In java I have something like this:

```
String data = "someFile.txt";
InputStream fin = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                                      .getResourceAsStream(data);
```

It basically initializes `fin` with the contents of a text file.

I am trying to convert this java code to objectiveC and I am really lost as how to do it for the **second line** i.e what is the equivalent of `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(data)` in objectiveC ?

**NOTE:** I can't directly read the file onto the `InputStream` as the data is globally provided in a string variable.

I am new to objectiveC and sorry if this is trivial but any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `NSData` from `NSString`.

Then create `NSInputStream` from `NSData`

```
NSInputStream* is = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: Slightly shorter: `[NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]`

Comment: I got the technique but actually the text file is in unicode, so will `NSUTF8StringEncoding` cause any problems?

Comment: Can I use it like this: `[NSInputStream inputStreamWithData: str]` without using the encoding? @MartinR

Comment: @Sibir, you can use any other encoding as you wish. For example `NSUnicodeStringEncoding`. And no, you can't use it without encoding, because `initStreamWithData:` waits for `NSData` object. `NSString` is n't inherited from `NSData`, so you need type conversion.